# Error in terminal: capture tag was never closed

Tags: terminal, jekyll, capture, liquid

I'm trying to develop multiple column layout in my Jekyll built blog with the capture variable. 
However I keep getting an error in terminal when I want to --watch my site on localhost:4000/.

As far as I can see I'm using the correct opening and closing tag. Hope anyone knows what's going on. Thanks!

```
---
layout: post
title: 
description: ""
tags: []
imageURL: 
published: 
---

{% capturesection1 %}

Some text

{% endcapture %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes:

1. You need to put a blank between `capture` and the name of the variable you are capturing into: `{% capture section1 %}` instead of `{% capturesection1 %}`
   *(see the [example in the docs](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/logic#capture))*
2. There are empty lines between `capture` and `endcapture`.
   I didn't find this anywhere in the docs, but on my machine *(Windows, if that matters)* I get an error as soon as there's an empty line between both.
   Capturing multiple lines is okay though, as long as none of them is completely empty.

So either of this will work:

```
{% capture section1 %}Some text{% endcapture %}
```

or

```
{% capture section1 %}
Some text
{% endcapture %}
```

Comment: Thank you Christian! I never got an alert that I had a message. So a bit late, but still very much appreciated.